# Image not appearing in template in django 2.1

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-templates

[full file tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZ3Fb.png)

I am making a profile page for my website.  I have followed a couple peoples instructions online and I did what they said (i.e. media_url, media_root, changes to my urls.py).  I register my superuser through the admin page, and I give it a profile.  When trying to get my image, it does not display. Here is my code:

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Pic = models.ImageField(default='default.png', blank=True, upload_to='img')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=70, default='Bensons', unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70, unique=True, default='ben@email.com')

    def __str__(self):

        return self.address
```

settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '=ytl^8!j@t(^c5eile%%x(l3hvkekc$z#_t538+%a)p2uvsr!+'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.1.192']

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'crispy_forms',
    'index.apps.IndexConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth', #yoohoo
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'campaign.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'campaign.wsgi.application'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'index'

LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'index'
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'index/media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

website/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('index.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

template/profile.html

```
{% extends 'index/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <div class='container'>

    <img src='{{ user.Profile.Pic.url }}' width='240'

  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

view.py

```
@login_required
def Profile_view(request):
    user = User

    return render(request, 'index/profile.html', {'title': 'profile'}, {'user' : user})
```

I think its a problem in the template, but I am not sure. It works fine when I try to open the image in admin.

Comment: Inspect image element and check the path of image and verify whether image is there or not in that path

Comment: Also `img` closing tag missing

Comment: when i inspect element it says <img src=(unknown) width="240">

Comment: The image source is unknown because there is no column named url in your table Profile; Instead of user.Profile.url you have to write user.Profile.pic.url

Comment: You have added image in Pic, hence the image path is user.profile.Pic.url instead of user.profile.url

Answer (score 1):

You specified

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
# <----There doesn't seem to be a url field on the model
Pic = models.ImageField(default='default.png', blank=True, upload_to='img')
address = models.CharField(max_length=70, default='Bensons', unique=True)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=70, unique=True, default='ben@email.com')

def __str__(self):

    return self.address
```

The Template

Change

```
<img src='{{ user.Profile.url }}' width='240' />
```

To

```
<img src='{{ user.Profile.Pic.url }}' width='240' />
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage

Comment: what do you mean by 'url field'

Comment: ```user.Profile.url``` is not an image field on your Profile model

Comment: how do I add it

Comment: @abhinavchavali ‘url’ gives the relative path of the image stored in media/img folder

Comment: @KeshavGarg It still isn't working. is there a problem with my settings, urls, or views

Comment: @abhinavchavali you need an instance of the user `user = User` should be `request.user`

Answer (score 0):

Try Installing pillow with this command in command terminal:
`pip install pillow`